# Converting jrxml file to csv file: Leading zeros getting truncated

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a conversion from jrxml to pdf. I am sending the data as **001** in the DTO but while displaying the same in the *Excel* it is becoming as **1**. Below is the code that is been used for displaying the data.

**Code:**

```xml
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement style="table 5_CH" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="71" height="26" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <property name="class" value="sortable"/>
    </reportElement>
       <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
        <font pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
        <paragraph lineSpacing="Single" firstLineIndent="3" spacingAfter="5"/>
       </textElement>
     <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{reference}]]>  
     </textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

I need to show the leading zeros also. So pls let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "zero padding."  A quick search for `jasper reports zero padding` turned up useful results.  Perhaps one of them is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Charles But I have given the input as `String` so ideally it should not truncate the string rt ?

Comment: @Che Why you did not use the *JRXlsExporter* for making *xls* file?

Comment: @AlexK I have not implemented this `CSV` completely. It was part of some enhancement. Can you tell me how will `JRXlsExporter` help me for the above issue.

Comment: @AlexK If you think there is an alternate and a better way than the below answer then pls write a new answer through which I can learn.

Comment: @Che I've add the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the *MS Excel* application for viewing *csv* file. The *csv* is just a plain-text format, it does not contain information "how to show data". The view of this sort of data depends on your viewer only. Therefore you can try to use *JRXlsExporter* or *JExcelApiExporter* or *JRXlsxExporter* exporters - for constructing report in *Excel* format (*xls* or *xlsx*).

Let's look at an example. We take *csv* file as datasource.

The *csv* file data (**excel_data.csv**):

```
number_as_string,date,number_as_int
001,2013-09-23,1
002,2013-09-22,3
3,2013-09-21,4
004,2013-09-20,5
```

The configuration of datasource in *iReport* will be:

[image]

We will use the [*net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern) and [*net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type) properties in sample for getting information in format we want.

Our template will be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test_excel_formatting" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="952b781d-520d-4a76-aa59-f635b8759fbe">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="number_as_string" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="date" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <field name="number_as_int" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="667b6ca6-bf50-404e-8ef1-c654456ed8e4" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="88" height="42" backcolor="#FF99CC"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Number as String, without pattern]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="080a5cc0-fa66-4b11-a3d3-f0b8a4e69204" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="88" y="0" width="88" height="42" backcolor="#9999FF"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Number as Int, without pattern]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="d1fc6219-2e33-4cc9-b4fe-4ac2b5365102" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="176" y="0" width="104" height="42" backcolor="#99FFCC"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Date without pattern]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="991837d7-a1ab-44ed-8177-756cfae9d369" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="280" y="0" width="104" height="42" backcolor="#9999FF"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Number as Int with common pattern]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="d38154af-2017-4e10-a176-4d66e5cc9f96" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="384" y="0" width="104" height="42" backcolor="#9999FF"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Number as Int with xls pattern]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="17f57019-8691-4643-abdb-ab15afe63f36" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="488" y="0" width="104" height="42" backcolor="#9999FF"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Number as Int with common and  xls pattern]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="f4f506bf-9511-4e1e-805b-8752a98e91ea" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="592" y="0" width="104" height="42" backcolor="#99FFCC"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Date with common pattern]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="dffea96e-1dfa-47e0-8551-dd417c25ecbd" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="696" y="0" width="104" height="42" backcolor="#99FFCC"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Date with common pattern]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="3d11d568-6e2c-4373-af7d-fa79b99a2908" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="88" height="20" backcolor="#FF99CC"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{number_as_string}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="8b8f968e-ca6d-44d0-bc2e-50a4773d0a6f" mode="Opaque" x="88" y="0" width="88" height="20" backcolor="#9999FF"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{number_as_int}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="943a468b-491d-4955-b0c0-58d550536234" mode="Opaque" x="176" y="0" width="104" height="20" backcolor="#99FFCC"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="000000">
                <reportElement uuid="52a26b66-1ef5-4f77-a4a2-900a606a1171" mode="Opaque" x="280" y="0" width="104" height="20" backcolor="#9999FF"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{number_as_int}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="c26be152-fae4-4a85-ae55-c70e27739a87" mode="Opaque" x="384" y="0" width="104" height="20" backcolor="#9999FF">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern" value="00000000000000"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{number_as_int}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="00000">
                <reportElement uuid="fab0fba1-1718-479d-841b-6cbaf1963a0b" mode="Opaque" x="488" y="0" width="104" height="20" backcolor="#9999FF">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern" value="00000000000000"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{number_as_int}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy">
                <reportElement uuid="07552f94-56c8-413d-8dd8-5b5c667c81cf" mode="Opaque" x="592" y="0" width="104" height="20" backcolor="#99FFCC"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="844449f9-1578-4729-b911-18bdd17f8cd4" mode="Opaque" x="696" y="0" width="104" height="20" backcolor="#99FFCC">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern" value="dd mmmm yyyy"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The report's design in *iReport* looks like this:

[image]

In example I've set report's property ***net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type*** as ***true***.

I've put the **number_as_string** field without any patterns into the first column (pink color).

I've put the **number_as_int** field into the columns number 2, 4, 5, 6 (blue color).

- The column #2 does not contain any pattern.
- The column #4 does contains common *textFields* element's ***pattern*** attribute. I've used the ***000000*** value.
- For column #5 I've set ***net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern*** property. I've set ***00000000000000*** value for it.
- And the column #6 is a mixed variant - I've set ***net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern*** property and the *textFields* element's pattern.

I've put the **date** field into the columns number 3, 7, 8 (green color).

- The column #3 does not contain any pattern. The default pattern will be used.
- The column #7 does contains common *textFields* element's ***pattern*** attribute. I've used the ***dd-MMM-yyyy*** value.
- For column #8 I've set ***net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern*** property. I've set ***dd mmmm yyyy*** value for it.

The result (generated file in *Excel* format) will be:

[image]

**Notes**:
As you can see the first column contains data in original format.

The column #6 contains data in format set with help of ***net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern*** property. This property is "stronger" than the *textFields* element's ***pattern*** attribute.

The *Excel* file was generated with help of *iReport 5.2.0* with *XLS Preview*, *XLS Preview (Using JExcel API)* and *Excel 2007 (XLSX) Preview* options - the result was the same.

Comment: +1 got it. But I don't want to change the existing one .. :( I have already spent enough time on this. But from now on I will use your approach .. which seems better to these tasks. And also accepting your answer for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I figured the answer after lot of googling. I am sending the data as `String` but still it is truncating the leading zeroes.

The problem is, excel is taking this input as a number and truncating the leading zeros.

In order to stop excel from doing this, prefix the data with **`'=' and append our data in double quotes`**.

i.e, the input which I am sending is `001` which should be converted as `"=" + "\"" + "001" + "\""` so it becomes **="001"** then in excel it gets to know that the given one is a `text` and it is not going to truncate the leading zeroes.

**Addendum:**

I even had trouble while displaying the date. The requirement is, date should be displayed as `04 Apr 2013` but if I send the same to excel it is converting it to `04-Apr-2013` which is not acceptable in my case.

The same logic above holds good here too,

just append '=' to the input data. Say `"=" + "\"" + 04 Apr 2013 + "\""` so it becomes 
**`="04 Apr 2013"`**. Now the date is taken as a `text`and is displayed as it is.

Hoping this will help someone .. :)